# Formatting multi-d array in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the following output format from a CI query and subsequent JSON_encode:

```
{"clients":{"id":"3","name":"Client Number1"},{"id":"2","name":"Client Number2"},{"id":"1","name":"Test Client"},{"id":"4","name":"Test Client2"}}
```

Combining the small functions in the controller and the model, I am using:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, name FROM clients ORDER BY name ASC');
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $arr['clients'][] = $row;
        }

        $json = json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        echo $json;
```

This code outputs (below) which includes the array index values ("1", "2"... etc.)  How can I remove these index values from the result?  Thanks for any help you may be able to give.  This one is not a deal-breaking crisis.  I could parse them out on the other side of the transaction... but thought the omniscient SO might know how to do this more elegantly!!

```
{"clients":{"0":{"id":"3","name":"Client Number1"},"1":{"id":"2","name":"Client Number2"},"2":{"id":"1","name":"Test Client"},"3":{"id":"4","name":"Test Client2"}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I was wrong.

Apparently all objects in PHP's json_encode print as associative arrays, and thus it always prints the keys.  At least, that's the vibe I got from the page on [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in the PHP manual.

Removing JSON_FORCE_OBJECT (and using `$query->result_array()`) gets rid of the keys, but isn't **exactly** what you're looking for:

```
{"clients":[{"id":"3","name":"Client Number1"},{"id":"2","name":"Client Number2"},{"id":"1","name":"Test Client"},{"id":"4","name":"Test Client2"}]}
```

Comment: Ha!  Thanks!  You must have been typing at the same time as me.  :)  I'll happily give you the up arrow and check mark!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Trevor... I appreciate the help.  You actually pointed me in the right direction.  I had forgotten that the 'JSON_FORCE_OBJECT' parameter might be messin' things up.  In fact it was... see below:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, name FROM clients ORDER BY name ASC');
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $arr['clients'][] = $row;
        }

        $json = json_encode($arr); // Note JSON_FORCE_OBJECT removed
        echo $json;
```

This code outputs:

```
{"clients":[{"id":"3","name":"Client Number1"},{"id":"2","name":"Client Number2"},{"id":"1","name":"Test Client"},{"id":"4","name":"Test Client2"}]}
```

I think that simply allowed a JSONArray (hence the square brackets) to live inside the JSONObject... I can live with that.

Thanks again Trevor!